# why functions still work if i passed a non-variable arguments

Tags: c++, c, function, variables

suppose i have defined a `int x` with a value of 10, along with a function `int printnumber` with required parameters `int num`.

```
int printnumber(int num) {/*it will print the number*/ }
```

I called the function `printnumber`, passing the variable x  as an argument. expected that it will print the value of 10

```
printnumber(x);
```

however, it also works if I just passed a raw 10 number as a parameter

```
printnumber(10);
```

why is this?

Comment: You've told the function to expect an `int` as its parameter. Both `10` and `x` (as you've defined it) are `int`s. I'm a bit lost as to what problem you think you see here.

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? `printnumber` needs an `int` value. You gave it an `int` value. What's wrong with that? It won't work without storage if it needs a *pointer* to an `int` (in which case the pointer must point to somewhere, or be `NULL` and explicitly not pointing anywhere), but it's asking for the raw value, the value need not come from any particular place.

Comment: Case #1, the value of x is passed. Case #2, the value 10 is passed. Simple. `printnumber()` receives a value and prints it (or so we are led to believe). btw: is this 'C' or 'C++'???

Comment: Tip: People who know how the programming language works are not going to be surprised by the language working. So if you want to know why something works, you should add an explanation of why you thought it would not work.

Comment: This is explained in any [beginner c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). These are also available as PDFs for free.

Comment: Why wouldn't they? Give a good reason.

Answer (score 1):

Because x and 10 are both convertable to  int, try to change

> `int printnumber(int num) {/*it will print the number*/ }`

On

`int printnumber(int& num) {/*it will print the number*/ }`

And see what will change

Answer (score 1):

> however, it also works if I just passed a raw 10 number as a parameter

Because `10` is an `int` prvalue and hence it can be used as an argument to a function that has a parameter of type `int` and takes that argument **by value**.

On the other hand, if you were to change the parameter to a nonconst lvalue reference, then the call `printnumber(10)` will no longer works because a prvalue `int` cannot bind to a  nonconst lvalue reference parameter.

This is trivial and is explained in any beginner [c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).